# Devise on heroku with a custom domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, devise

So I am getting this odd issue which is only on my one heroku instance.  I have an rails/devise app deployed to heroku with a custom domain, and when I go to log in, it redirects to the herokuapp domain and not the custom domain. All other urls, links stay on the custom domain but anytime authentication is checked it redirects to the herokuapp domain.  Is there something missing?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your DNS set up properly with a CNAME instead some sort of URL cloaking?